How to prove explicitely that the parametrization of $S^3$ is 1-to-1 almost everywhere and in which points is it not 1-to-1?
Consider the three-sphere $S^3$ of radius $R$ defined as the submanifold of points in $\mathbb{R}^4$ satisfying
$
X^2 + Y^2 + Z^2 + W^2 = R^2. \tag{1}$
Consider the parametrization:
$\begin{eqnarray}
X &=& R \sin \chi \sin \theta \cos \phi, \quad Z = R \sin \chi \cos \theta, \\
Y &=& R \sin \chi \sin \theta \sin \phi, \quad W = R \cos \chi.
\end{eqnarray}
$
I need to know how to deduce the  appropriate specification ranges for the angles and show explicitly that the parametrization is 1-to-1 almost everywhere and tell in which points is it not? I have a partial answer, but some doubts:
I guess I can define $\phi \in [0, 2\pi)$, $\theta \in [0,\pi], \chi \in [0,\pi]$ ? Or should I defined them on open intervals or closed intervals? I just took inspiration from 3-dim spherical coordinates but I would like to know if there is a more formal whay to justify that the range for $\chi$ should be that one? Isn't it a problema defining this ranges that are not open sets when I want to work with charts later?

How to proof that the parametrization is 1 to 1 almost everywhere explicitely I have no idea, plese help me with this.

I was told that to analyse the ranges I have to look at the jacobian determinant I got $J=-r^3sin^2 \chi \sin \theta$ , which is $ 0 $ at $\chi=0$ or $\pi$ or $\theta=0$ or $\pi$
I computed this considering R as a variable, to have a 4 by 4 determinant so the jacobian $\frac{\partial(X,Y,Z,W)}{\partial( R,\phi,\theta,\chi)}$, I am not sure how to justify this, because in reality the transformation goes fom a subset of $R^4$ to $S^3$, so  I think the jacobian matrix should be $\frac{\partial(X,Y,Z,W)}{\partial(\phi,\theta,\chi)}$? but I get a non-square matrix so I cannot compute the determinant. Once I get the jacobian ,What are the points where the parametrization is not 1-1? Only two points as a friend suggested where the parametrization is not 1 to 1 i.e the ones corresponding to $\chi=0$ and $\chi=\pi$ which in cartesian coordinates correspond to $(R,0,0,0)$ and $(-R,0,0,0)$ i.e the north and south poles ? Or should I also consider as I think the points where $\theta=0$, that is $(0,0,R\sin\chi,R\cos\chi)$  ?Then we have infinite points in addition to the north and south poles.Then I would say that the set of points where the parametrization is not one to one is


$$\{(R,0,0,0),(-R,0,0,0),(0,0,R\sin\chi,R\cos\chi);\chi \in [0,\pi]\}$$?

You can just plug in the definition of 1-to-1, and use algebra. No differentiation is needed.

@Trebor Is the jacobian an alternative method? I was told in a lecture I had to use the Jacobian.  Is my anwer about the points where there is no bijectivity correct?

$y = x^3$ has the jacobian zero at $x = 0$, but it's still bijective.

You mean homomorphic almost everywhere or diffeomorphic almost everywhere?

@rushusuixing Not sure the problem just said 1 to 1, I guess that means homeomorphically

It suffices to consider $R=1$ which makes notation a bit easier.
I think you have checked that $(X,Y,Z,W) \in S^3$ if
\begin{eqnarray}
X &=& \sin \chi \sin \theta \cos \phi, \quad Z = \sin \chi \cos \theta, \\
Y &=& \sin \chi \sin \theta \sin \phi, \quad W = \cos \chi.
\end{eqnarray}
Let us first consider the standard parameterization of the $1$-sphere (= unit circle) $S^1 \subset \mathbb R^2$. This is given by $c^1(\phi) = (\cos \phi, \sin \phi)$ with $\phi \in [0,2\pi]$. We have $c^1(\phi) = c^1(\phi')$ iff $\phi = \phi'$ or $\{\phi, \phi'\} = \{0, 2\pi\}$. Thus the parameterization is $1$-$1$ almost everywhere. By restricting it to $[0,2\pi)$ we get a bijection; it is a matter of taste which one prefers. Let us work with $\phi \in [0,2\pi)$.
Let us next consider the $2$-sphere $S^2 \subset \mathbb R^3$. It is the disjoint union of the circles $S^1_t = S^2 \cap (\mathbb R^2 \times \{t\})$ with $t \in [-1,1]$, where $S^1_t$ is degenerate to a point for $t = \pm 1$. We can write $t = \cos \theta$ with a unique $\theta \in [0,\pi]$. Then it easy to see that $S^1_t$ is a circle in the plane $\mathbb R^2 \times \{t\}$ with radius $r_t = \sin \theta$. Note that $r_t = 0$ for $t = \pm 1$. This shows that
$$c^2(\phi,\theta) = (\sin \theta \cos \phi, \sin \theta \sin \phi, \cos \theta)$$
with $(\phi,\theta) \in [0,2\pi)  \times [0,\pi]$ is a parameterization of $S^2$ which is $1$-$1$ almost everywhere. It is injecetive on $[0,2\pi) \times (0,\pi)$ and the sets $[0,2\pi) \times \{0\}$ and $[0,2\pi) \times \{1\}$ are mapped to a single point (north and south pole of $S^1$).
The $3$-sphere $S^3 \subset \mathbb R^4$ can be treated similarly. It is the disjoint union of the spheres $S^2_t = S^3 \cap (\mathbb R^3 \times \{t\})$ with $t \in [-1,1]$, where $S^2_t$ is degenerate to a point for $t = \pm 1$. We can write $t = \cos \chi$ with a unique $\chi \in [0,\pi]$. Then $S^2_t$ is a $2$-sphere in $\mathbb R^3 \times \{t\}$ with radius $r_t = \sin \chi$. Again $r_t = 0$ for $t = \pm 1$. This shows that
$$c^3(\phi,\theta,\chi) = (\sin \chi \sin \theta \cos \phi, \sin \chi \sin \theta \sin \phi, \sin \chi \cos \theta, \cos \chi)$$
with $(\phi,\theta,\chi) \in [0,2\pi)  \times [0,\pi] \times [0,\pi]$ is a parameterization of $S^3$ which is $1$-$1$ almost everywhere. It is injective on the set
$$[0,2\pi) \times (0,\pi) \times (0,\pi) $$
and non-injective on
$$[0,2\pi) \times \left(\{0,1\} \times [0,\pi] \cup  [0,\pi] \times \{0,1\}\right)$$
which is a subset of the boundary of $[0,2\pi) \times [0,\pi] \times [0,\pi]$.
The above considerations have shown that the map
$$c^3 : [0,2\pi) \times [0,\pi] \times [0,\pi] \to S^3$$
is a parameterization of $S^3$ (which means nothing else than that $c^3$ is surjective). Forgetting the above steps to find $c^3$, we can also formally explore when
$$c^3(\phi,\theta,\chi) = c^3(\phi',\theta',\chi') \tag{1}$$
and thereby determine the preimages of points $x \in S^3$.
Since $\cos$ is injectiv on $[0,\pi]$, we see that $(1)$ implies $\chi = \chi'$.

If $\chi = 0$, then $\cos \chi = 1$ and $\sin \chi = 0$. This shows that $(c^3)^{-1}(0,0,0,1) = [0,2\pi) \times [0,\pi] \times \{0\}$.

If If $\chi = \pi$, then $\cos \chi = -1$ and $\sin \chi = 0$. This shows that $(c^3)^{-1}(0,0,0,-1) = [0,2\pi) \times [0,\pi] \times \{\pi\}$.


Let us now consider the case $\chi \in (0,\pi)$. Then $\cos \chi \in (-1,1)$ and $\sin \chi \ne 0$. Thus $(1)$ implies that
$$c^2(\phi,\theta) = c^2(\phi',\theta') . \tag {2}$$
This implies that $\theta = \theta'$.

If $\theta = 0$, then $\cos \theta = 1$ and $\sin \theta = 0$. This shows that $(c^3)^{-1}(0,0,\sin \chi, \cos \chi) = [0,2\pi) \times \{ (0,\chi)\}$.

If $\theta = \pi$, then $\cos \theta = -1$ and $\sin \theta = 0$. This shows that $(c^3)^{-1}(0,0,-\sin \chi, \cos \chi) = [0,2\pi) \times \{ (\pi,\chi)\}$.


Summarizing, we conclude that all points of the form $(0,0,Z,W) \in S^3$ have non-trivial preimages. For $(0,0,0,\pm 1)$ see above. For $(0,0,Z,W)$ with $0 < Z < 1$ we get $(c^3)^{-1}(0,0,Z, W) = [0,2\pi) \times \{ (0,\arccos W)\}$ and when $-1 < Z < 0$ we get $(c^3)^{-1}(0,0,Z, W) = [0,2\pi) \times \{ (\pi,\arccos W)\}$.
Let us finally consider the case $\theta \in (0,\pi)$. Then $\cos \theta \in (-1,1)$ and $\sin \theta \ne 0$. Thus $(2)$ implies that
$$c^1(\phi) = c^1(\phi'),$$
i.e. $\phi = \phi'$. This shows that all points $(X,Y,Z, W) \in S^3$ with $X \ne 0$ or $Y \ne 0$ have single-point preimages.
